# How to prove that the softmax function is not invariant under scalar multiplication.

Tags: summation, vectors, exponential-sum, invariant-theory, invariance

I want to prove that the softmax function is not invariant under scalar multiplication.

[image]

[image]

How to continue from there to prove that S(x)i is not equal to S(xc)i ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a direction you should follow.

Take instead the problem to solve to be that it is invariant to scalar multiplication.

A way to disprove it (i.e. that it is actually not scalar multiplication invariant) is to look at full example using a scalar of your choice (not 1 as it's not really a multiplication). (proof by contradiction to the opposite problem)